# AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'monkey_patch'

Tags: python-2.7, concurrency, celery, eventlet

I want to use concurrency using celery in python.
I have a tasks.py file, which is a web crawler using BeautifulSoup.
The imports I have done are:

```
from celery import Celery
import eventlet
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')
```

For celery worker, I am using this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --pool=eventlet -c 1000
```

Error:

```
mayank@mayank-Studio-1558:~/cognite/test$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --         pool=eventlet -c 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 28, in main
maybe_patch_concurrency()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 124, in maybe_patch_concurrency
patcher()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 89, in _patch_eventlet
  eventlet.monkey_patch()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'monkey_patch'
```

I want to perform tasks using 1000 threads.
I have tried importing eventlet, and then did:

```
eventlet.monkey_patch(socket=True, select=True)
eventlet.import_patched('monkey_patch')
```

still didn't work and same error.

Please if anybody could help, would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: What does `print eventlet` tell you is imported?

Comment: importing **eventlet** as I know, is the pool of events, used as mentioned above in the command.
source: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html

Comment: No, `eventlet` is a library Celery uses; but if you have a module with the same name, then that breaks.

Comment: So, what do you suggest me to do? I am new to celery and eventlet both. how to remove this error?

Comment: That is why I am asking you to add the line `print eventlet` to your code, after the `import`.

Comment: I did. Got the same error. Sadly.

Comment: Right, open the python interpreter, type in `import eventlet`, then `print eventlet`; use the same interpreter as what you use for celery.

Comment: <module 'eventlet' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/__init__.pyc'>

This is what i got.

Comment: And `eventlet.monkey_patch` resolves?

Comment: **Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) **
**[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2**
**Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.**
**>>> import eventlet**
**>>> eventlet.monkey_patch()**
**Traceback (most recent call last):**
**  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>**
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'monkey_patch'**
**

Comment: It's still the same. :(

Comment: Then your installation of `eventlet` is the wrong eventlet version. The `monkey_patch` method has been part of the project at least since version 0.9.5.

Comment: I used **pip install eventlet**

Comment: The `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` location is installed by Ubuntu / Debian, IIRC.

Comment: i uninstalled and reintalled usin apt-get..
It worked. Thank you so much Martijn :)

Comment: What does `dpkg --search /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/__init__.py` say? That package is in your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was coming because of eventlet installation.
Previously I used pip install eventlet,
but **sudo apt-get install eventlet** worked for me, which resolves the **monkey_patch** dependency.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-eventlet

Answer (score 1):

I have just run into this problem, and for me, the problem was not having python development headers in my system. While I was trying to install eventlet via pip, I got this error:

```
In file included from greenlet.c:5:0:

greenlet.h:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

but it was saying that eventlet is installed anyway, except I got the same error when I tried to use it. So how to fix it in my case is:

```
pip uninstall eventlet
apt-get install python-dev (For Ubuntu, use your distros package manager)
pip install eventlet
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason is that you have `eventlet.py` or `eventlet.pyc` somewhere in your `sys.path`, maybe in your project tree.

Try this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
import eventlet
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')
```